# Можно ли повесить событие на текстовый узел в DOM?

Tags: javascript

проверял, стандартными способами не получается, мб есть способ? Можно конечно, каждый узел в html тег обернуть и ловить событие, но мб есть другой более красивый способ?. При клике на текстовый узел событие не генерируется.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

for (var i = 0; i < input.childNodes.length; i++) {
  input.childNodes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Ura');
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" tabIndex="1">Pro<b>gra</b>mist</div>
```

Comment: Как проверяли? Добавьте в вопрос примеры.

Comment: Пример добавил.

Comment: Судя по описанию целью клика может быть [только Element](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) - text node - не является элементом.

Comment: Какая цель преследуется добавлением обработчика клика на текст?